# Algorithm for multiplying infinite decimals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

What is the (best) algorithm for multiplying two real numbers based on their decimal expansions? Obviously the algorithm can't be completed but I mean an algorithm that will successively approximate it and give a rule for the $n$th decimal number.

Comment: Can you give an example to make your statement more clear?

Comment: Any computer or calculator less than 20 years old has a decent algorithm to multiply numbers. The speed depends very much on the electronic components.

Comment: @Qwerty Let  a be the sum from minus infinity to k of a_k *10^k where a_k is some se uence with range {0,1,2.3,4,5,6,7,8,9} and b is defined similarly. Find (ab)_k   .

Comment: @ajotatxe The relative speed of different algorithms on the other hand does not. And (if it is pertinent) I was  looking for an algorithm for a human computer to carry out (don't worry; I don't have any students).

Comment: Check out the algorithm for multiplication of two numbers using a Chinese abacus. https://threesixty360.wordpress.com/2009/06/25/multiplying-on-an-abacus/

Answer (score 3):

The simplest is just do long multiplication as usual, except you only fill in the leading digits that you need (i.e. enough to determine whether or not there is a carry) rather than working right to left.

There is an edge case that you won't have enough information to determine the carry should the calculation be that you either have lots of trialing $9$'s and no carry or lots of trailing $0$'s and a carry... either you'll eventually settle the issue, or you're computing something like $0.\bar{3} \cdot 3.\bar{0}$, and both choices are correct: $1.\bar{0} = 0.\bar{9}$.

(this is actually a serious theoretical problem in some computational models — it's the reason why constructive real analysis doesn't represent real numbers by their decimal expansion)